# Trying to Use FFT to Analyze Audio Signal in Python

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing

I've been trying to use FFT to get a frequency of a signal, and I'm having a bit of trouble dealing with it. I found a site that talked about using FFT to analyze and plot a signal here:

http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/python/2001/01/31/numerically.html?page=2

But I've run into an issue implementing it with Python 2.7. EDIT I updated the code with the improved version. This one works, actually, and plots the waveforms (a bit slowly) onto a chart. I'm wondering if this is the correct method for reading frames, though - I read that even numbered array indices are for the left-channel (and so the odd-numbered ones would be for the right, I suppose).

So, I guess that I should read however many frames, but divide it by the sample width, and then sample every other even frame for the left channel if it's stereo, huh?

```
import scipy
import wave
import struct
import numpy
import pylab

fp = wave.open('./music.wav', 'rb')

samplerate = fp.getframerate()
totalsamples = fp.getnframes()
fft_length = 256 # Guess
num_fft = (totalsamples / fft_length) - 2

#print (samplerate)

temp = numpy.zeros((num_fft, fft_length), float)

leftchannel = numpy.zeros((num_fft, fft_length), float)
rightchannel = numpy.zeros((num_fft, fft_length), float)

for i in range(num_fft):

tempb = fp.readframes(fft_length / fp.getnchannels() / fp.getsampwidth());

up = (struct.unpack("%dB"%(fft_length), tempb))

temp[i,:] = numpy.array(up, float) - 128.0

temp = temp * numpy.hamming(fft_length)

temp.shape = (-1, fp.getnchannels())

fftd = numpy.fft.fft(temp)

pylab.plot(abs(fftd[:,1]))

pylab.show()
```

The music I'm loading in is some that I made myself.

EDIT: So now, I'm getting the audio file read through reading the frames, and dividing the current number to read by the number of channels and the number of bits per frame. Am I losing any data by doing this? This is the only way that I could get any data at all - otherwise it would be too much data for the file handler to read into the struct.unpack function. Also, I'm trying to separate the left channel from the right channel (get the FFT data for each channel). How would I go about doing this?

Comment: try implementing a check for `len(tempb)`. According to http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#struct.unpack it must be exactly the right length, and `readframes` will read 'up to' `fft_length` bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used scipy's version of numpy/numarray in a long time, but seek out the function [`frombuffer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html).  It is a lot easier to use than trying to shuffle all of the data through `struct.unpack`.  An example reading the data using [`numpy`](https://numpy.org):

```
fp = wave.open('./music.wav', 'rb')
assert fp.getnchannels() == 1, "Assumed 1 channel"
assert fp.getsampwidth() == 2, "Assuming int16 data"
numpy.frombuffer(fp.getnframes(fp.readframes()), 'i2')
```

Keep in mind that wave files can have different data types in them and multiple channels, so be aware of that when unpacking.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, but I got another error - ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (512) (256) < Any other suggestions? I probably should just start from square one and learn more about the core functionality of reading sound files into a buffer...

Comment: I don't know about starting from square one, but it would be good to learn a bit about the APIs you are trying to use and what they do.  To handle the error you mentioned, you can perform a slice on the array and then set the `.shape` attribute appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Shane, and I did read up a bit and managed to get it working. However, I would like to be able to read the separate left and right channels - do you happen to know how exactly that works? The only way that I was able to read the frames from the file was to divide the total number of frames by the number of bytes, and the number of channels, thereby making it mono...? Or is the resulting array still in stereo?

Comment: Wave files interleave the channels in order for each frame.  The numpy way to separate the channels is to change the shape of the array.  Assuming you matched the `getsamplewidth()` to the matching numpy data type, you could set the resulting shape `res.shape = (-1, fp.getnchannels())`.  Then you could get channel 0's data with `res[:,0]` and channel 1's data with `res[:,1]`.

Comment: Hey, maybe you can elaborate a bit - I'm missing exactly how you get the different channels. What do you mean by 'match the getsamplewidth() function to the matching numpy data type'?